# What task to select in tasksel during lubuntu alternate install to get a default system

Tags: lubuntu, alternate, tasksel

I'm installing Lubuntu 14.04.1 from the alternate Image. At the "tasksel" step I would like to select the same tasks that would be installed with the desktop installer.

There's a task called "Lubuntu desktop" Is that all I need to select? Or is something like "Samba Server" "Print Server" included in the dekstop install?

Added: It's not Lubuntu but During Debian 8 installation I found "Print Server" and sth like "Base Desktop" and ".... System tools" ticked by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `Lubuntu Desktop` task is all that is required. If you loot at `/usr/share/tasksel/ubuntu-tasks.desc`:

```
Task: lubuntu-desktop
Section: user
Description: Lubuntu Desktop
 This task provides the Lubuntu (Ubuntu LXDE environment).
Key: 
 lubuntu-desktop
Packages: task-fields
```

In Ubuntu, each of the major flavour has a `-desktop` package named after it. Starting from an installation of `ubuntu-standard` or `ubuntu-minimal`,  installing the `-desktop` package is all that's needed to get the corresponding flavour setup. In this case, you can see that this task installs the `lubuntu-desktop` package, which is exactly what you need.

If a default Lubuntu installation comes with a Samba server or a print server, then `lubuntu-desktop` will depend on these directly or indirectly. So you do not need to select these tasks unless you explicitly want to install them.